# Powershell GUI combo box

Tags: powershell, combobox

The issue is at `$groups` when ran | where members -like `$users`
I'm not sure if `$users` is the right variable since It cant out put what is needed to the text box. When I run the script nothing come ups besides the username where I also want to see the groups that the user belongs to. Please help.
            Function resultWGroups () {
               $y = $GenTextbox.Text
               $SecondGenFormwGroups= New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
               $SecondGenFormwGroups.Text= 'Script'
               $SecondGenFormwGroups.Autosize=$true
               $SecondGenFormwGroups.StartPosition= 'centerscreen'

```
           $TexBoxwGroups= New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
           $TexBoxwGroups.Size= New-Object System.Drawing.Size(500,230)
           $TexBoxwGroups.Multiline= $true
           $TexBoxwGroups.text =''
           $TexBoxwGroups.ScrollBars='Vertical'
           $TexBoxwGroups.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(20,140)

        $ListUsers = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox
        $ListUsers.Width = 600



        $ListUsers.add_selectedindexchanged({$TexBoxwGroups.Text=$listusers.Text
        $Groups
        })
## searching for groups
## also the issue
        $Groups = Get-ADGroup -Properties * -Filter * -SearchBase "dc=example,dc=com" | where members   -like *$Users* | Select
      -Property Name
       ## searching for users
        $Users = Get-ADUser -filter * -SearchBase "dc=example,dc=com" |Select-String -Pattern $y

        Foreach ($User in $Users){
        $ListUsers.Items.Add($User)

        }

        $SecondGenFormwGroups.Controls.Add($TexBoxwGroups)
        $SecondGenFormwGroups.AllowDrop = $true
        $SecondGenFormwGroups.Controls.Add($ListUsers)
        $SecondGenFormwGroups.ShowDialog()

        }

## This is just the box with out the groups
         Function result (){
        $x = $GenTextbox.Text
        $SecondGenForm= New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
        $SecondGenForm.Text= 'Script'
        $SecondGenForm.Autosize=$true
        $SecondGenForm.StartPosition= 'centerscreen'
        $SecondGenForm.AutoScaleMode.value__.Equals(3)
        $ComboBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox
        $ComboBox.Width = 600
        ##searching for users
        $Users = Get-ADUser -filter * -SearchBase "dc=example,dc=com" |Select-String -Pattern $x
        Foreach ($User in $Users){
        $ComboBox.Items.Add($User);
        }
        $SecondGenForm.Controls.Add($ComboBox)
        $SecondGenForm.ShowDialog()
        $SecondGenForm.Dispose()
         }
        Function search-aduser () {
        $GenForm= New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
        $GenForm.Text= 'Script'
        $GenForm.StartPosition= 'centerscreen'
        $GenForm.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(300,200)
        ##
        $Username= New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
        $Username.Text= 'What is user name'
         $Groupschoice= New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label 
        $Groupschoice.Location= New-Object System.Drawing.Point(90,65)
         $Groupschoice.Text= 'do you want groups'

        $GenTextbox= New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
        $GenTextbox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,40)
        $GenTextbox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(260,20)
         $GenTextbox.AcceptsReturn =$true
        $YesButton= new-object System.Windows.Forms.Button
        $YesButton.text = 'yes'
        $YesButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(75,90)
        $YesButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(50,20)
        $YesButton.add_click({resultwGroups})
        ##some buttons
        $NoButton= new-object System.Windows.Forms.Button
        $NoButton.text = 'no'
        $NoButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(140,90)
        $NoButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(50,20)
        $NoButton.add_click({result})
        ##bulding the form
        $GenForm.Controls.Add($Groupschoice)
        $GenForm.AcceptButton = $YesButton
        $GenForm.Controls.Add($YesButton)
        $GenForm.Controls.Add($NoButton)
        $GenForm.Controls.Add($GenTextbox)
        $Username.AutoSize=$true
        $Groupschoice.AutoSize=$true
        $GenForm.Controls.Add($Username)
        $GenForm.Controls.Add($GenTextbox.Select())
        $GenForm.ShowDialog()
        $GenForm.Dispose()
         }
```

Answer (score 0):

To get a user's group membership you need to use `Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership`

The most efficient way would be to resolve that command when the user is selected using the combobox and populate their group list at that time.

Something like this:

```
Function resultWGroups () { 

    $y = $GenTextbox.Text
    $SecondGenFormwGroups= New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
    $SecondGenFormwGroups.Text= 'Script'
    $SecondGenFormwGroups.Autosize=$true
    $SecondGenFormwGroups.StartPosition= 'centerscreen'

    $TexBoxwGroups= New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
    $TexBoxwGroups.Size= '500,230'
    $TexBoxwGroups.Multiline= $true
    $TexBoxwGroups.text =''
    $TexBoxwGroups.ScrollBars='Vertical'
    $TexBoxwGroups.Location = '20,140'

    $ListUsers = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox
    $ListUsers.Width = 600

    ## searching for users
    # test user
    $y = "john"

    $Users = Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(anr=$y)" -SearchBase 'OU=Standard Users,OU=Users,DC=company,DC=com' | Select Name, SamAccountName, DistinguishedName

    Foreach ($User in $Users){
        $ListUsers.Items.Add($User.DistinguishedName)
    }

    $ListUsers.add_selectedindexchanged({
        $TexBoxwGroups.Text=$listusers.Text
# Find groups for selected user
        $UserGroups = Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity ($listusers.Text) | Select Name
# Append each group to textbox
        $UserGroups.Name | ForEach {
            $TexBoxwGroups.AppendText($_ + "`r`n")
        }
    })

    $SecondGenFormwGroups.Controls.Add($TexBoxwGroups)
    $SecondGenFormwGroups.AllowDrop = $true
    $SecondGenFormwGroups.Controls.Add($ListUsers)
    $SecondGenFormwGroups.ShowDialog()
}
```